# Renaming/Merging App Store tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

I'm referring to these 4 tags:

- [windows-store](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-store)
- [windows-apps](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-apps)
- [windows-store-app](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-store-app)
- [app-store](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/app-store)

---

1. I think [app-store](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/app-store) should be renamed to something like [apple-app-store](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/apple-app-store) because the term "App Store" is no longer exclusive to Apple's applications store.
2. I don't think there's a need for all the 3 windows store/apps/store-apps tags. I think we can remove one of them for sure.

Comment: You're right. I've merged all `[windows-apps]` into `[windows-store-app]`. This should at least clear up part 2) of your question.

Comment: Great. Regarding the [app-store] tag - I thought about it because I recently saw someone tagging a Windows Apps question with [windows][app-store].

Comment: As for part 1), it probably should be called `[mac-app-store]`, because that's the official name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Update:* This is completed. We now have [mac-app-store](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mac-app-store). The general app store tag is free.

---

So, it appears [there's only one question](https://superuser.com/questions/307983/app-store-for-windows) where [app-store](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/app-store) is used in a general way and not referring to the Mac App Store. We can retag this later.

I'd propose renaming [app-store](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/app-store) to [mac-app-store](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mac-app-store), but not synonymizing.

This would probably leave room for the [app-store](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/app-store) tag to be a general tag for all app stores unless someone starts using it for a certain app store (Windows, OS X, …) again. Which we'd need to watch out for.